# Android Showing Battery level is giving error

Tags: android

Hello Every one I am trying to show the battery level in a textview, But its giving me error.
my Logcat error and code is given below.

### Logcat

```
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599): Process: com.Designproshop.solarchargerprank, PID: 9599
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.Designproshop.solarchargerprank.MainActivity$1@41b021c0
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at com.Designproshop.solarchargerprank.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:28)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
01-03 21:28:14.992: E/AndroidRuntime(9599):     ... 9 more
```

### MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   private TextView contentTxt;
   private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
      contentTxt.setText(Integer.toString(level)+ "%");
    }
  };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
     getActionBar().hide();
      setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
       new CountDownTimer(5000,1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){} 
        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
          //set the new Content of your activity
          MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.chargingactivity);
        }
        }.start();
        contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.btrylevel);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}}
```

What I am doing wrong?? Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check the object contentTxt is not null. You can have a synchronisation issue leading to call receiver before getting contentTxt initialized. 
Otherwise check intent is not null.